# How to obtain user's public IPv4 address using WebRTC?

Tags: javascript, ip, webrtc, client-side

I tried many different codes, But all of them only returned local IP address of the user. (e.g. 192.168.1.2).

How may I obtain user's public IPv4 address using WebRTC? (e.g. 104.200.21.83)

I know **it's possible**  because a [website](https://www.expressvpn.com/webrtc-leak-test) could show my leaked public IPv4 address even when I used VPN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a popular proof-of-concept:

https://github.com/diafygi/webrtc-ips

For me, it was only sending back my private IP. It appears you can get around this by changing the server IP:

https://github.com/diafygi/webrtc-ips/issues/33

The site you linked to uses the server address `stun:stun.l.google.com:19302`, which returned my public address as expected.

Comment: The website can show my real IP address (without VPN) even if I use VPN to browse the website. If it doesn't figure it out using WebRTC, so how does it do the trick?

Comment: ...this is using WebRTC. This proof-of-concept exploits the same vulnerability that the website you linked uses.

Comment: WOW! I just replaced the default URL with the one you mentioned! It works!

Answer (score 0):

Here a small Powershell sample that gives you want you want:

```
# get public IP via WebRTC-Protocol in Chrome-browser (even if VPN has another IP)
# carsten.giese@googlemail.com

$tmpFile = New-TemporaryFile
Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe' "--no-first-run --headless --disable-gpu --dump-dom https://www.expressvpn.com/webrtc-leak-test" -RedirectStandardOutput $tmpFile -wait
$result = Get-Content $tmpFile
Remove-Item $tmpFile -Force -ea 0
$ip = [regex]::Match($result, '(?ms)(?<=<th class="ip">).*?(?=</th>)').value

cls
write-host "Your public IP as reported by WebRTC: $ip" -f y
```

Of course it would be way smarter to execute Chrome in the background and run only the required Java-function as mentioned above. But I was not able to get that solved.

Answer (score -1):

Don't get me wrong but the client (where the browser is running) might not know his public IP. I would somehow host a small php on a server in the internet which prints the $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], call it from JS, gather the address back into a JS var...sounds dirty!

Edit: WRONG ANSWER, got the asking user wrong, somehow.

Comment: Hey dear! You're right but I'm doing a research on web security. WebRTC helps a programmer get user's real IP address even when they're using VPN.

Comment: Might be I am not getting the whole story, but I do not see how a client computer in a natted IPv4 network could gather the ip address of the wan interface of the router without asking the router, or by querying it from the outside like in the example described above.

Comment: Just try the website using VPN and a browser which is configured to use VPN and has WebRTC enabled...